# PHP Order Second Array ASC by Key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array inside an array that has the filename, modification time and size, but I need to be able to order the array either ascending or descending by each one of these properties.

I have the following, which gets the information

```
//SCAN THE DIRECTORY
$directories = scandir($dir);
$directinfo = array();
foreach($directories as $directory){
    if ($directory === '.' or $directory === '..') continue;
    if(!stat($dir.'/'.$directory)){

    } else {
        $filestat = stat($dir.'/'.$directory);
        $directinfo[] = array(
            'name' => $directory,
            'modtime' => $filestat['mtime'],
            'size' => $filestat['size']
        );
    }
}
```

The array is structured as so:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [name] => 0 Organisation Details 
        [modtime] => 1398164749 
        [size] => 4096
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [name] => 1 Permission Form 
        [modtime] => 1398164749 
        [size] => 4096 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [name] => 6 Invoices 
        [modtime] => 1400802471 
        [size] => 4096 
    ) 
)
```

and then use this to output:

```
foreach($directinfo as $dirInfo){
    foreach($dirInfo as $key=>$drInfo){
        echo "Output: ".$key."=>".$drInfo."<br />";
    }
}
```

But I need to arrange the array before this, and somehow make it so I don't need two arrays or I'm suspecting the ordered output wouldn't work.

I've looked at `array_multisort` but can't figure out how this would work in this instance.

Any help with this is really appreciated.

Comment: There's a great table [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) describing which sorting function will be suitable for which scenario. Otherwise, can you provide an example of your array structure?

Comment: You can save one call to stat with `if (!($filestat = stat ...)) { } else { $directinfo[] = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using example #3 on the [`array_multisort` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$directories = array( 
array('name'=>'filec','modtime'=>'12303403434','size'=>'12401'),
array('name'=>'fileb','modtime'=>'12303403432','size'=>'12400'), 
array('name'=>'filez', 'modtime'=>'12304445405','size'=>'65200')
);

// Obtain a list of columns
$name = $modtime = $size = array();
foreach ($directories as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key]  = $row['name'];
    $modtime[$key] = $row['modtime'];
    $size[$key] = $row['size'];
}

// Sort the data with name ascending, modtime ascending, size ascending
array_multisort($name, SORT_ASC, $modtime, SORT_ASC, $size, SORT_ASC, $directories);

print_r($directories);
```

Online demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e949275658fac1c965b2300d877cb4ca514c4f6)

Comment: Thank you @cOle2 its worked perfectly. I had come across this before but couldnt get it working, but it is now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use usort:

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});

var_dump($arr);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/lZoUsO

Comment: Not sure how this helps, as that assumes I have one array, whereas I have an array inside an array. So how would I use this, given the data I've provided?

Comment: @SeanMcCabe you haven't actually provided any data, it would definitely help if you did

Comment: @SeánMcCabe Please check the fiddle - it is working exactly how you require. $a and $b are elements of the array, themselves being individual arrays. The array $arr is sorted on the name elements of the internal arrays